# How to run the websocket without shell command

Tags: php, shell, websocket

I'm building a real time message system and used this http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket/comment-page-1 tutorial as an example.

In my local PC it worked find. I have a shared server and hosting provider doesn't allow me to access shell command on my server.

Can anyone help me on this. Is there any way I can execute this shell command in a PHP file?

Answer (score -2):

you can start web-socket from PHP  like:

```
 exec("php -q ".your_path_of_directory."/server.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Thanks your response. Could you elaborate this more?

Comment: you have to make a one function that will called when your web-socket page is load. and in it you have to define this code. so when your page execute it will execute its shell command. so your web-socket connection can be made.

Comment: If they're in a shared hosting environment, the exec command is almost certainly turned off.  If it's not turned off, then the hosting service is incredibly insecure and you want to leave them as soon as possible to protect your data.  In the unbelievably unlikely event their shared server allows exec AND is secure, there is absolutely no way they would ever approve of a WebSocket server, and the person asking the question is probably violating their terms of service by even trying.

The real answer is: Get VPS.